# React hide dropdown menu when lose focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am following Fireship's [Advanced Dropdown Menu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IF6k0uZuypA) video on YouTube. After I finished the video, I noticed that the menu stays open until the page reloads. Is there a way to make it disappear when it loses focus, for example when the user clicks outside the menu? Not only when the user clicks on the nav icon.

Comment: I believe [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-menu-b9w1e?file=/src/components/NavItem.js) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `button` is ref for a dropdown trigger element, and `isOpen` add a class to open the dropdown:

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
const button = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => window.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    if(button.current && button.current.contains(ev.target)) {setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
    else {setIsOpen(false)}
}));
```

on the DOM, the trigger element:

```
<div ref={button}>...</div>
```

the dropdown menu

```
<div className={isOpen ? 'open' : ''}>...</div>
```

Comment: The ref to the dropdown is a div, not a button is it possible to modify your code to work with a div instead?

Comment: its doesn't metter what element it is. `button` is just a variable name.. on your div add `<div ref={button}>...</div>`

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' when I click on the screen.

Comment: My fault. you should get the `current` value: `button.current && button.current.contains(ev.target)`

Comment: There is a small error in your code change buttons.current to button.current. I can't do it because of the 6 characters minimum need change.

Comment: thanks @ChristofferHennie, looks like someone already read your comment and fixed it :)

Comment: This doesnt handle focus on tab click